# How to set a listener for a button inside a customised cell to get the textfield data in swift ?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view which contains two types of customised cells. Once I hit the the cell with Custom title, the last cell toggles down with three text fields and a save button. What I want to do is to save the values of the textfields once the Save button has been clicked on.

Here is how I have constructed my table:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if editionMood == .notEditing {

        let cell : WeightGoalPlanCell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WeightTargetDateCell" ) as! WeightGoalPlanCell
        cell.labelOfNumber?.text = String(planArray[indexPath.row].numberOfDays)
        cell.labelOfDays?.text = "Days"
        cell.labelOfLevel?.text = planArray[indexPath.row].hardshipLevel
        cell.labelOfCalorie?.text = "Calories Defeshits"
        cell.labelOfWeightLossPerWeek?.text = "Lost per week"
        cell.valueOfCalorieDeficit?.text = String(planArray[indexPath.row].calorieDificitValue)
        cell.valueOfWeightLossPerWeek?.text = String(planArray[indexPath.row].weightToBeLost)
        cell.finalDate?.text = String(planArray[indexPath.row].goalDate)


        return cell

        }else {
            while indexPath.row < ( planArray.count  ) {

                let cell : WeightGoalPlanCell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WeightTargetDateCell" ) as! WeightGoalPlanCell
                cell.labelOfNumber?.text = String(planArray[indexPath.row].numberOfDays)
                cell.labelOfDays?.text = "Days"
                cell.labelOfLevel?.text = planArray[indexPath.row].hardshipLevel
                cell.labelOfCalorie?.text = "Calories Defeshits"
                cell.labelOfWeightLossPerWeek?.text = "Lost per week"
                cell.valueOfCalorieDeficit?.text = String(planArray[indexPath.row].calorieDificitValue)
                cell.valueOfWeightLossPerWeek?.text = String(planArray[indexPath.row].weightToBeLost)
                cell.finalDate?.text = String(planArray[indexPath.row].goalDate)

                return cell

            }
                let cell : editingCellWeightPlan = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditWeightTargetDateCell") as! editingCellWeightPlan
                    cell.calc?.placeholder = "8"
                    cell.daysValue?.placeholder = "7"
                    cell.weeklyLost?.placeholder = "100"

                return cell

        }

    }
```

And here is the customised Cell classes :

```
class WeightGoalPlanCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelOfNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOfDays: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOfLevel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOfCalorie: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOfWeightLossPerWeek: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueOfCalorieDeficit: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueOfWeightLossPerWeek: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var finalDate: UILabel!


}

class editingCellWeightPlan : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var daysValue: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var calc: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var weeklyLost: UITextField!

}
```

My problem is that the textfields are not defined globally, but the function that serves the save button is global. How can I get the values for those textfields ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S83b.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from the description provided, I'll suggest you to replace cell with three textfield with tableFooter view with save button in it. Then you can easily capture values from these text fields into your view controller.